# squid (reverse proxy) configuration

Tags: firewall, ip, proxy, squid

I would like to configure squid in such way, so that only specific (public) ip (reverse proxy), could connect to the server, but I don't know how... can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Huh, use `iptables`?

Comment: can you give me some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Squid this is done by specifying the public IP address in `http_port`, and using loopback address for the web server and Apache may be configured like in `httpd.conf` to listen on the loopback address:

```
Port 80
BindAddress 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just read the squid.conf file. The default installation on Ubuntu only works for localhost.  You will need to set up an ACL to enable access.  This can include any address or address you choose.

You may want to review instructions for [Setting up a Squid Proxy on Ubuntu](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/setting-up-squid-proxy-on-ubuntu/). They should be applicable to most platforms.

Comment: I tryed to do this, but when I add some public IP, squid doesnt start... I read somewhere that squid can work like a reverse proxy... but I don't know how to configure this.

Comment: @Wolfy: For a reverse proxy I would configure Apache (or nginx) to act as a reverse proxy.  Apache has very good controls to restrict access by IP address and/or require a password.  Apache can be configured as to cache responses if that is what you need.